# How do I show battery percentage in GNOME Panel without using any extension?

Tags: gnome-shell, indicator, battery, notification-area

By default GNOME (and hence Ubuntu 17.10 and later releases) doesn't show battery percentage in the notification area of the Panel. There are [GNOME extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) (for example [Battery Percentage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1191/battery-percentage/), [Battery Percentage and Time](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1771/battery-percentage-and-time/), [Battery Percentage and Time Compact](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2575/vince-battery-percentage-and-time/) etc.) which do the job.

Is there a way to attain the goal without using any extension?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Open *dconf Editor* and navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/show-battery-percentage`. Then disable "*Use default value*" and select **True** in the "*Custom value*" field.

Alternatively just open *Terminal* and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage true
```

---

Same settings can be found in *(GNOME) Tweaks* under **Top Bar**:

[image]

Comment: dconf Editor didn't work for me on Ubuntu 17.10, but using gsettings solved the problem, thanks!