# How do you make your battery indicator more detailed in GNOME Shell?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, indicator, battery

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME 3. I would like to have a battery indicator that changed in more than 3 steps. 
The current icon goes from one to three bars. If you look at most phones, the battery slowly increases, from bottom to top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use some [GNOME extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) to achieve your goal. For example

- [Dynamic Battery](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1213/dynamic-battery/)

  > Makes battery indicator show battery charge level more precisely
  >   [image]
- [Circular Battery Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1244/circular-battery-indicator/)

  > Displays a circular battery indicator
  >   [image]

Alternatively, you can enable showing the battery percentage next to the battery icon following this Q&A: [How do I show battery percentage in GNOME Panel without using any extension?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946711/how-do-i-show-battery-percentage-in-gnome-panel-without-using-any-extension)